# Does unchecking an asp.net web forms checkbox undo the CheckedChanged event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I have CheckedChanged event handler that hides a row from a gridview when the checkbox is checked. Now when I uncheck the checkbox, nothing happens. I actually want the row that gets hidden to be visible when the checkbox is unchecked. So I want the opposite to happen when I uncheck the checkbox. Currently the event handler does hide the row but I want the row to re-appear when I uncheck the checkbox

The checkbox:

```
 <div class="row mt-4 mb-2" style="width: 50%; margin: auto;">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="check-label-Prof-Clients" >
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkProfClients" class="check-trading" runat="server" Enabled="true" AutoPostBack="true" 
                            ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="true" Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="chkProfClients_CheckedChanged"/>
                        <label class="form-check-label" style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: 400;" for="chkProfClients">
                                 Only Show Profitable Clients
                        </label>     
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The checkbox CheckedChanged event handler:

```
protected void chkProfClients_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= gridProfitMargin.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var profitValue = Convert.ToDouble(gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Cells[13].Text);
        if (profitValue <= 0)
        {
            gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Visible = true;
        }
    }       
}
```

I have "Autopostback = true". But still, nothing happens when I uncheck the checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You run a loop, but you don't check if the check box is being checked, or un-checked.

So, you need to ALSO check the state/status of the check box, and based on if the check box = true, then the code and logic has to be different then the case when the check box - un-checked.

So, then this:

```
protected void chkProfClients_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= gridProfitMargin.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var profitValue = Convert.ToDouble(gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Cells[13].Text);
        if (chkProfClients.Checked)
        {
            if (profitValue > 0)
                gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Visible = true;
            else
                gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // don't care - always show
            gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And, I suppose you could shorten the code a bit, say with this:

```
protected void chkProfClients_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= gridProfitMargin.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var profitValue = Convert.ToDouble(gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Cells[13].Text);
        if (chkProfClients.Checked)
        {
            gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Visible = (profitvalue > 0);
        }
        else
        {
            // don't care - always show
            gridProfitMargin.Rows[i].Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

but, this comes down to what you find more readable here.

Try the first one. So, you have a loop for each row of the gridview, but you not taking into account if the check box is checked (true), or it is not.